# System.Exception error numbers

Tags: silverlight

In a Silverlight project I am working on; I am occasionally seeing exceptions with messages like `System.Exception: 3000 An error has occurred`. The numbers vary, though - I have seen 3000, 3001, 4001, and 3137. These appear when playing/accessing different media, and Google searches confirm that they are media related.

These obviously mean something specific; but none of them are obvious in meaning. Are these procedurally generated? Is there an easy way besides scouring forums/Google to determine what the different numbers mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you referring to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/07/08/silverlight-plug-in-error-messages.aspx

```
    Error Code  Error Message
    1001    AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR
    2000    Document is not well-formed XAML.
    2001    DTDs are not allowed.
    2002    Entity references to named entities other than lt, gt, amp, apos, and quot are not allowed.
    2003    Entity definitions are not allowed.
    2004    Only UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings are supported.
    2005    Unknown namespace %0.
    2007    Unknown element: %0.
    2008    Cannot specify the value multiple times for properties.
    2009    Cannot specify content for %0 and set its %1 property at the same time.
    2010    %0 does not support %1 as content.
    2011    %0 does not support text content.
    2012    Unknown attribute %0 on element %1.
    2013    Attribute %0 value is out of range.
    2014    The attribute %0 is read only and cannot be set.
    2015    Cannot declare custom namespaces in JavaScript.
    2016    Cannot specify both Name and x:Name attributes.
    2017    Null is not a legal value for attribute %0.
    2018    The element %0 does not support attributes.
    2019    Xaml may not use base type names, use %0 instead.
    2020    Invalid Property: %0.
    2021    Invalid enum value.
    2022    Unknown Color: %0.
    2023    %0 is not an event.
    2024    Invalid attribute value %0 for property %1.
    2025    AG_E_PARSER_ATTRIBUTE
    2027    AG_E_PARSER_ELEMENT
    2028    The name already exists in the tree: %0.
    2030    Property element %0 cannot be used inside another property element.
    2031    The property element %0 must appear before other content.
    2033    Cannot specify the value multiple times for property: %0.
    2034    Elements in a ResourceDictionary must have x:Key or x:Name attribute.
    2035    The element is not valid in the given namespace.
    2036    XamlReader.Load() does not accept event handlers.
    2100    AG_E_INIT_CALLBACK
    2101    Failed to initialize the application's root visual
    2102    Invalid source file specified on Silverlight plug-in. Expected Uri for application file
    2103    Invalid or malformed application: Check manifest
    2104    Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings
    2105    Failed to load pre-requisites for the application
    2106    Failed to load the application. It was built with an obsolete version of Silverlight
    2107    Splash screen file needs to be on the same domain as the application
    2108    Failed to download the splash screen
    2150    Failed to load a platform extension. Possibly corrupt or non-existent file: %0
    2152    Failed to download a platform extension: %0
    2153    Failed to load a platform extension. Possibly corrupt or invalid file: %0
    2201    AG_E_RUNTIME_INVALID_CALL
    2202    AG_E_RUNTIME_FINDNAME
    2203    AG_E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE
    2204    AG_E_RUNTIME_GETVALUE
    2205    AG_E_RUNTIME_ADDEVENT
    2206    AG_E_RUNTIME_DELEVENT
    2207    AG_E_RUNTIME_METHOD
    2208    AG_E_RUNTIME_GETHOST
    2209    AG_E_RUNTIME_GETPARENT
    2210    AG_E_INVALID_ARGUMENT
    2211    AG_E_RUNTIME_HTML_ACCESS_RESTRICTED
    2212    Animation target not specified.
    2213    Cannot resolve TargetName %0.
    2214    Cannot resolve TargetProperty %0 on specified object.
    2215    %0 cannot be used to animate property %1 due to incompatible type.
    2216    Multiple animations in the same containing Storyboard cannot target the same property on a single element.
    2217    KeyTime property on KeyFrame object must be set to a non-negative TimeSpan value.
    2218    Operation is not valid on an active Animation or Storyboard.  Root Storyboard must be stopped first.
    2219    Operation is not allowed on a non-root Storyboard.
    2220    Cannot determine Storyboard Duration.
    2221    Shader file %0 not found.
    2222    Invalid shader.
    2250    AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_UNKNOWN_ERROR
    2251    AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_ACTIVATION
    2252    AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_ASSEMBLY_DOWNLOAD
    2253    AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_ASSEMBLY_LOAD
    2254    AG_E_PARSER_UNKNOWN_TYPE
    2255    AG_E_PARSER_BAD_TYPE
    2256    AG_E_PARSER_BAD_NATIVE_TYPE
    2257    AG_E_PARSER_CREATE_OBJECT_FAILED
    2258    AG_E_PARSER_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND
    2259    AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_TYPE
    2260    AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE
    2261    AG_E_PARSER_ROOT_NOT_CUSTOM
    2262    AG_E_PARSER_NAMESPACE_NOT_SUPPORTED
    2263    AG_E_PARSER_MISSING_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE
    2264    AG_E_PARSER_INVALID_XMLNS
    2265    AG_E_PARSER_INVALID_CLASS
    2266    AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_BAD_DLR_SCRIPT
    2267    AG_E_PARSER_INVALID_XCODE_TAG
    2268    AG_E_PARSER_ELEMENT_IGNORED
    2269    Elements in a ResourceDictionary must not set both x:Name and x:Key, or x:Key twice
    2270    Attribute x:Key set on an invalid object, only objects in a ResourceDictionary can have x:Key
    2271    Improper syntax for Static Resource (ie: {StaticResource Key})
    2272    Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key %0
    2273    Elements in the same ResourceDictionary cannot have the same x:Key
    2274    AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND
    2275    Invalid characters in Source Uri.
    3000    AG_E_UNABLE_TO_PLAY
    3001    AG_E_INVALID_FILE_FORMAT
    3002    AG_E_NOT_FOUND
    3003    AG_E_MEDIA_DISCONNECTED
    3004    Invalid ASX element
    3005    Invalid ASX attribute
    3006    Unsupported ASX element
    3007    Unsupported ASX attribute
    3008    ASX parse error
    4000    AG_E_ABORT_FAILED
    4001    AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR
    4002    AG_E_ACCESS_DENIED
    4003    AG_E_INVALID_POLICY
    4004    AG_E_MANAGED_EXCEPTION
    4005    XamlReader.Load() does not support x:Class.
    4006    Only the root element can have an x:Class attribute.
    4007    The root element must be <UserControl>, not a subclass of UserControl.
    4008    Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.
    4009    Element is already the child of another element.
    4010    The ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate must have a derivative of Panel as the root element.
    4011    Setting the Template property on a UserControl is not supported.
    4012    Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.
    4013    Cycle detected in merged resource dictionaries
    4014    Local values are not allowed in resource dictionary with Source set
    4015    This Style's hierarchy of BasedOn references contains a loop.
    4016    Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type of this style's target type.
    4017    A Style cannot be based on itself.
    4018    After a Style is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified.
    4019    Must have non-null value for TargetType.
    4020    '%0' is not a valid value for property '%1'.
    4021    Using NavigationState requires a hidden <iframe id='_sl_historyFrame'> element in HTML.
    4022    Mouse promotion can only be suspended on a primary TouchPoint’s down action.
    4023    Navigation is prohibited for this Silverlight application.
    6000    Unable to play protected content
    6001    Unable to individualize due to a network or protocol error
    6002    Unable to acquire license due to a network or protocol error
    6003    Unable to individualize due to an installation failure
    6004    Update of Silverlight required
    6005    Incorrect header format for protected media file
    6006    Unable to process license
    6007    Unable to acquire license due to an application specific error
    6008    Individualization disabled by user
    7000    unexpected end of input
    7001    unrecognized encoding
    7002    unable to switch the encoding
    7003    unrecognized input signature
    7004    whitespace expected
    7005    semicolon expected
    7006    '>' expected
    7007    quote expected
    7008    equal expected
    7009    wfc: no '<' in attribute value
    7010    hexadecimal digit expected
    7011    decimal digit expected
    7012    '[' expected
    7013    '(' expected
    7014    illegal xml character
    7015    illegal name character
    7016    incorrect document syntax
    7017    incorrect CDATA section syntax
    7018    incorrect comment syntax
    7019    incorrect conditional section syntax
    7020    incorrect ATTLIST declaration syntax
    7021    incorrect DOCTYPE declaration syntax
    7022    incorrect ELEMENT declaration syntax
    7023    incorrect ENTITY declaration syntax
    7024    incorrect NOTATION declaration syntax
    7025    NDATA expected
    7026    PUBLIC expected
    7027    SYSTEM expected
    7028    name expected
    7029    one root element
    7030    wfc: element type match
    7031    wfc: unique attribute spec
    7032    text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input
    7033    leading \'xml\'
    7034    incorrect text declaration syntax
    7035    incorrect xml declaration syntax
    7036    incorrect encoding name syntax
    7037    incorrect public identifier syntax
    7038    wfc: pes in internal subset
    7039    wfc: pes between declarations
    7040    wfc: no recursion
    7041    entity content not well formed
    7042    wfc: undeclared entity
    7043    wfc: parsed entity
    7044    wfc: no external entity references
    7045    incorrect processing instruction syntax
    7046    incorrect system identifier syntax
    7047    '?' expected
    7048    no ']]>' in element content
    7049    not all chunks of value have been read
    7050    DTD was found but is prohibited
    7051    illegal qualified name character
    7052    multiple colons in qualified name
    7053    colon in name
    7054    declared prefix
    7055    undeclared prefix
    7056    non default namespace with empty uri
    7057    'xml' prefix is reserved and must have the http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace URI
    7058    'xmlns' prefix is reserved for use by XML
    7059    xml namespace URI (http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace) must be assigned only to prefix 'xml'
    7060    xmlns namespace URI (http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/) is reserved and must not be used
    7061    invalid decimal
    7062    invalid hexidecimal
    7063    invalid unicode
    7064    invalid encoding
    8001    Upgrade required
    8002    Browser restart required
```

Comment: Yes! I couldn't find anything like this in my extensive Googling! Thanks, this will be very handy.